# max from aggregated results elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

i am using elastic search to perform a simple aggregation. this aggreagtion gives total transactions from each country:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distribution": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Transactions": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "transactions"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me correct result as below:

```
"buckets": [
{
"key": "Australia",
"doc_count": 31,
"Transactions": {
"value": 9
}
}
,
{
"key": "Canada",
"doc_count": 31,
"Transactions": {
"value": 1
}
}
```

**How do i modify the query to return the `max` value of transaction from aggregated results.** here in this case output should be `australia` with value `9`.

Comment: Try this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html

Comment: @rad11 i tried that but that can only be used when i dont need to perform aggregation but just find the max among a set of documents i assume, this is what i understand . but in my case first i need to find aggregation thenn among those results i have to find max value

Comment: if you know how max_aggregation can be use in above query please help me clarify it

Comment: So maybe this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html

Comment: @rad11 thanks for reply i wnat to know if i can just get the aggregations and then find max or min in python would it faster or scripted metric is the correct way to go from performance perspective